# Maven3 eclipse:eclipse does not work - Not running eclipse plugin goal for pom project

Tags: eclipse, maven-plugin, maven-3

I have a problem with maven 3 running on Windows7 64 bit. When I execute maven eclipse:eclipse (I use maven-eclipse-plugin 2.8), maven does not create any configuration. I just get the following log:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building sesame-connector
[INFO]    task-segment: [eclipse:eclipse]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Preparing eclipse:eclipse
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] [eclipse:eclipse {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Not running eclipse plugin goal for pom project
[INFO] Using Eclipse Workspace: C:\workspace
[WARNING] Workspace defines a VM that does not contain a valid jre/lib/rt.jar: C
:\Program Files\Java\jre6
[INFO] Adding default classpath container: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAIN
ER
```

My eclipse plugin configuration looks fine, so I really can not understand why it does not work:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>

    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>                    
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
        <version>2.8</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Does anybody experience such a behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a mistake in my pom file - the package declaration: `<package>pom</package>`. When I change it to `jar`, everything start to work. The eclipse plugin does not generate any eclipse files for a pom projects.

Comment: thanks. you should accept your own answer. I almost missed it, and the other answer doesn't realy helps if you don't understand maven's output. (and the title of your question contains it, and that's exactly what i was searching for)

Answer (score 0):

From the following log snippet, it looks like you are trying to generate eclipse configuration for a project which does not have any source files.

```
Not running eclipse plugin goal for pom project
```